# Why do immigrants want to come to the UK when its cost of living is so high?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

As a working visa holder, I realize that the cost of living in the UK is horrifying.

A British whole breakfast that would cost only £3 in Asia costs £10 in the UK.

Public transport wise, it only cost less than £1 in Asia, while in the UK it costs you £2.50 for the same distance.

Britain has horrible weather, diminishing street security, and high taxes including the TV license fee.

I really don't see why people kept preaching about the UK's high living interests when the cost of living there is so high.

Comment: Do immigrants keep pouring in? This question could backup its premises with more sources. And what about costs of living relative to wages?

Comment: Buying breakfast for a pound is cheap, but getting shot because you're the wrong surname/sect/side of the street is free.

Comment: It's hard to take a question like this seriously when it goes on about *horrible weather*.  Not least given the ever increasing climatic issues facing a lot of countries where immigration is coming from.  See also https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8460/why-is-the-drive-for-undocumented-migration-so-strong-between-france-and-the-uni

Comment: Horrible weather? If you don't like the weather in Britain, just wait a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 8):

Countries with higher salaries frequently have also higher costs of living so something that looks like a heaven from the side may easily not be.

Many emigrants keep supporting they old parents and siblings that remained in the home country they are from. This is where the absolute earning matters, even if the emigrants themselves do not live a lot better.

Comment: Your first sentence is exactly it: the higher cost of living in Western countries is offset by the higher wages available there.

Comment: Elaborate absolute earning. 
The ratio is the same, what seems the remain will also has the same ratio.
The only difference would be determined by exchange rate.
But after period of time, exhange rate will be even out by government policy and printing of money. 
Unless your country money is worthless, don't see why you would want to live in high cost high wage country to compete with the locals.
Besides, sometimes the ratio of income in less develop country may be even better with cheaper cost of living, like japan etc. Same island country, cheaper transport. :)